# create pinned products showcase section based on scroll in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have  a UI which looks like this"

[image: UI]

I have tabs on the left and product showcase on the right, in one of the sections of a page. The issue is, I want the default browser scroll to stop when it reaches this section in page until all the tabs are shown one by one. Once all tabs are complete, I want the default window scroll to continue.
Is there any react.js (or javascript/jquery) library for this type of functionality?

Comment: Voted to close as the question lacks focus, detail, and appears to ask for recommendations.

Comment: You can ask what type of details do you want, did you not understand the question well? I will provide more details if you want. The last line (which seems to ask for a recommendation) doesn't mean that I am totally dependent to use a library, you can provide a code example if you want. Thanks, but I am really stuck

Comment: The reason nobody has responded yet is because this is a set of requirements rather than  a question about a specific problem with code.  What you want to do is clear from the requirements, but that alone does not make it a good question for SO.  Yet, if you share your html markup and provide more detail, such as what css framework is used, it might attract more interest and answers.

Comment: I guess it looks  more like a "how to do" rather  than a requirement... and I don't know what markup to share, nothing would be useful, as it is not a problem with the code, I am just converting UI to HTML.